# Google AdMob Unity plugin not working on old Android versions - ClassNotFoundException - is this expected behaviour?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

I am running the Google AdMob [HelloWorld sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/tree/master/samples/HelloWorld)  in Unity 2019.2.21f1 on Android and iOS devices. On the iOS devices I have tested it on (iPhone 8 with iOS 13.5.1, iPhone SE 2020 with iOS 13.5.1, as well as a couple of iPhone 5 devices with iOS 10.3.4), the app works fine, and I am able to display Banner Ads, Rewarded Ads and Interstitial Ads.

See this screenshot for an example of what this sample looks like when it is running on the iPhone SE, with a banner ad being displayed at the top of the screen:

[image]

Now, I would also like to get AdMob ads to work on Android devices. However, for my own personal testing, I only own a couple of older (and very cheap, even when they were new) Android devices, which I can't upgrade beyond **Android 6.0.1 and Android 5.1** respectively.

When I build the same sample for Android in Unity, I am able to deploy the app to the Android devices, but the banner ad at the top doesn't show up at all, and when I tap "Request Rewarded Ad", the app crashes. See below two screenshots:

[image][image]

To investigate this further, I have connected to my Android device via ADB, using `adb logcat -s Unity DEBUG`

Here is some of the output I am getting when the app tries to load the banner ad (**for full stack trace, see bottom of post**):

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener
... other output

... other output

... other output

... other output

... other output

AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
```

And here is the output I get when I try to load a rewarded ad by tapping the relevant button:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
```

I am not sure why these classes are missing on Android. Is there some other step I need to take to make AdMob ads work on Android devices? Or is this maybe due to the fact that these devices are running very old versions of Android, meaning these `ClassNotFoundExceptions` and the `NoClassDefFoundError` would not be thrown on newer Android devices? **Is there anything I can do to get these ads to work on said Android devices?**

**Full stack trace here:**

```
Chris@Chris-Air ~ % adb logcat -s Unity DEBUG



--------- beginning of system

--------- beginning of crash

--------- beginning of main

06-21 08:48:10.828 26342 26342 D Unity : CommandLine: 

06-21 08:48:10.853 26342 26342 I Unity : onResume

06-21 08:48:10.880 26342 26342 I Unity : onPause

06-21 08:48:10.914 26342 26357 D Unity : SetWindow 0 0xb7be6a40

06-21 08:48:10.914 26342 26357 D Unity : SetWindow 0 0xb7be6a40

06-21 08:48:10.998 26342 26342 I Unity : windowFocusChanged: true

06-21 08:48:11.046 26342 26357 D Unity : Enabling Unity systrace

06-21 08:48:11.072 26342 26357 D Unity : [VFS] Mount /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.apk

06-21 08:48:11.130 26342 26357 I Unity : SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 4, Memory = 1408mb

06-21 08:48:11.130 26342 26357 I Unity : SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf), 0 little (mask: 0x0)

06-21 08:48:11.131 26342 26357 I Unity : ApplicationInfo com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld version 1.0 build 0739718b-a9b5-4291-9d27-65a28d82d111

06-21 08:48:11.131 26342 26357 I Unity : Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.21f1 (9d528d026557)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled'

06-21 08:48:11.154 26342 26342 I Unity : onResume

06-21 08:48:11.161 26342 26357 D Unity : Mono path[0] = '/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed'

06-21 08:48:11.161 26342 26357 D Unity : Mono config path = 'assets/bin/Data/Managed/etc'

06-21 08:48:11.162 26342 26357 D Unity : PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)

06-21 08:48:11.163 26342 26357 D Unity : PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55408

06-21 08:48:11.163 26342 26357 D Unity : PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld

06-21 08:48:11.165 26342 26357 D Unity : Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.179.24 [Port] 55408 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 1873625426 [EditorId] 780879431 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(LGE_LG-M153@192.168.179.24) [Debug] 1 [PackageName] AndroidPlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...

06-21 08:48:11.165 26342 26357 D Unity : Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55408]...

06-21 08:48:12.174 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:8s

06-21 08:48:13.185 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:7s

06-21 08:48:14.193 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:6s

06-21 08:48:15.200 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:5s

06-21 08:48:16.210 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:4s

06-21 08:48:17.216 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:3s

06-21 08:48:18.226 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:2s

06-21 08:48:19.236 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:1s

06-21 08:48:20.246 26342 26357 D Unity : Remaining time:0s

06-21 08:48:21.207 26342 26357 D Unity : Timed out. Continuing without host connection.

06-21 08:48:21.207 26342 26357 D Unity : Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55408]

06-21 08:48:21.207 26342 26357 D Unity : Starting managed debugger on port 56426

06-21 08:48:21.207 26342 26357 D Unity : Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:56426

06-21 08:48:21.547 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Attaching window :0xb7be6a40

06-21 08:48:21.548 26342 26357 D Unity : InitializeScriptEngine OK (0x9ead6f00)

06-21 08:48:21.548 26342 26357 D Unity : PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55408]

06-21 08:48:21.586 26342 26357 D Unity : PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK

06-21 08:48:21.586 26342 26357 D Unity : AndroidGraphics::Startup window = 0xb7be6a40

06-21 08:48:21.586 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Attaching window :0xb7be6a40

06-21 08:48:21.597 26342 26357 D Unity : [XR] Discovering subsystems at path assets/bin/Data/UnitySubsystems

06-21 08:48:21.600 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.601 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Checking ES 3.1 support...

06-21 08:48:21.602 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] ES3.1 not supported

06-21 08:48:21.602 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1 RGB0 000 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.603 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGB0 000 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.604 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Found: ID[1] ES 3.0 RGB16 565 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.615 26342 26357 D Unity : GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1

06-21 08:48:21.616 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.616 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Request: ES 3.1 RGB0 000 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.617 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGB0 000 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.618 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Found: ID[1] ES 3.0 RGB16 565 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.626 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.637 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0

06-21 08:48:21.637 26342 26357 D Unity : extension is supported with value 0

06-21 08:48:21.645 26342 26357 D Unity : ANativeWindow: (480/854) RequestedResolution: (0/0) RenderingResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (480/854)

06-21 08:48:21.655 26342 26357 D Unity : Renderer: Adreno (TM) 304

06-21 08:48:21.655 26342 26357 D Unity : Vendor: Qualcomm

06-21 08:48:21.655 26342 26357 D Unity : Version: OpenGL ES 3.0 V@140.0 AU@ (GIT@I7d704ff208)

06-21 08:48:21.655 26342 26357 D Unity : GLES: 3

06-21 08:48:21.656 26342 26357 D Unity : GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT

06-21 08:48:21.656 26342 26357 D Unity : _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query

06-21 08:48:21.684 26342 26357 D Unity : OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics device ; Context level <OpenGL ES 3.0> ; Context handle -1207557632

06-21 08:48:21.687 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Attaching window :0xb7be6a40

06-21 08:48:21.693 26342 26357 D Unity : Requested framebuffer: resolution[480x854], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[on], samples[1]

06-21 08:48:21.693 26342 26357 D Unity : Created framebuffer: resolution[480x854], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[24/8], samples[0]

06-21 08:48:21.694 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Attaching window :0xb7be6a40

06-21 08:48:21.695 26342 26357 D Unity : Initialize engine version: 2019.2.21f1 (9d528d026557)

06-21 08:48:21.745 26342 26357 D Unity : Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly

06-21 08:48:21.752 26342 26357 D Unity : Script Patching: Patch files are not available, '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld/cache/ScriptOnly/2019.2.21f1/mono/patch.config' is missing.

06-21 08:48:22.968 26342 26357 D Unity : - Completed reload, in 1.223 seconds

06-21 08:48:23.184 26342 26357 D Unity : PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK

06-21 08:48:23.187 26342 26357 D Unity : Found 3 native sensors

06-21 08:48:23.190 26342 26357 D Unity : Sensor : Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.000000 / 0.01s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / STMicroelectronics

06-21 08:48:23.192 26342 26357 D Unity : Sensor : Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.000000 / 0.01s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / STMicroelectronics

06-21 08:48:23.206 26342 26357 D Unity : SetWindow 0 0xb7cf8608

06-21 08:48:23.207 26342 26357 D Unity : [EGL] Attaching window :0xb7cf8608

06-21 08:48:23.220 26342 26357 D Unity : ANativeWindow: (480/854) RequestedResolution: (0/0) RenderingResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (480/854)

06-21 08:48:25.338 26342 26357 D Unity : UnloadTime: 7.615209 ms

06-21 08:48:25.347 26342 26357 D Unity : UUID: a932359a92746509 => d436ae954935bfb66019d4d0218ae6c6

06-21 08:48:25.915 26342 26357 D Unity : Sensor : Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.000000 / 0.01s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / STMicroelectronics

06-21 08:48:25.919 26342 26357 D Unity : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:48:26.339 26342 26357 E Unity : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.

06-21 08:50:25.981 26342 26342 I Unity : onPause

06-21 08:50:26.026 26342 26357 D Unity : Sensor : Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.000000 / 0.01s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / STMicroelectronics

06-21 08:55:48.707 26342 26342 I Unity : onResume

06-21 08:55:48.757 26342 26357 D Unity : Sensor : Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.000000 / 0.01s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / STMicroelectronics

06-21 08:55:48.763 26342 26357 D Unity : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:476)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType(Method.java:183)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:672)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:58:46.578 26342 26357 E Unity : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.De

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)

06-21 08:59:36.159 26342 26357 E Unity : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.HelloWorld-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use google admob on an android device, but when I opened the app, it crashed.
i am not sure it is the same problem, but in the android manifest, you need to enable custom main android manifest file: edit>project settings>player>publish settings>enable use custom main android manifest file.
if you imported the package by yourself, you need to go to assets>plugins>android>AndroidManifest.xml and check if there is a comment that looks like this: "this file is automatically generated by unity. delete this comment to disable it.". if there is, delete it.
if you didn't do this already, add

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="your-Admob-Id-Here"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest file under the application tag.
also don't forget to add your app id by simply going to assets>google mobile ads>settings, check "google admob" and insert your app id: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431

anyway, you can check this guide: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start

Comment: Hi Itamar, unfortunately, this does not seem to be the issue I am experiencing. I checked the AndroidManifest.xml, and it does not have a comment saying"this file is automatically generated by unity. delete this comment to disable it.". Moreover, the manifest already has the meta-data tag with the correct name and appID. thanks though :)

Comment: Did you fix the problem? if not, try to logcat the app on android studio. that's how I found out my problem